# How to Extract underlying Type of a MSSQL Nullable Output Parameter

Tags: .net, sql-server

I am attempting to extract the underlying system type of a nullable SQL output parameter in .Net (note value is NULL also)

This type is shown as:

```
FullName = "System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]&"}
```

When attempting the following:

```
Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pinfo.parameterType)
```

This returns null but only for my Output parameters.

Is there an actual method to do this so I don't have to do the current string manipulation method as below?

```
if (pi != null)
            {
                t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.ParameterType) ?? pi.ParameterType;
                isOut = pi.IsOut;
            }
            if (isOut)
            {
                //output vars do weird 5#1T with types
                //FullName = "System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]&"}
                // so we to get the underlying type by this kludge for now.
                // need a better way in future
//
                if (t.Name == "Nullable`1&")
                {
                    int pos1 = t.FullName.IndexOf("[[") + 2;
                    int pos2 = t.FullName.IndexOf(",", pos1 + 1);
                    string tname = t.FullName.Substring(pos1, pos2 - pos1);
                    t = System.Type.GetType(tname);

                }
            }
```

The SQL test procedure so we can test the returned variables:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTestOutputVariableHandling]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ErrorSeverity INT,
    @ErrorState INT,
    @idVar UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT ,
    @boolVar BIT OUTPUT,
    @stringVar NVARCHAR(255) OUTPUT,
    @intVar INT OUTPUT,
    @decVar DECIMAL(18,2) OUTPUT,
    @singleVar REAL OUTPUT,
    @doubleVar FLOAT OUTPUT,
    @dateVar DATETIME2 OUTPUT
    AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from

    SET @idVar= NEWID()
    SET @boolVar = 1
    SET @stringVar = 'Test String'
    Set @intVar = 1000
    SET @decVar = 234.67
    SET @singleVar = 7474747.587598
    SET @doubleVar = 8876543212345.98767
    SET @dateVar = GETDATE()


SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Things
IF (@ErrorSeverity > 0) 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @erMsg NVARCHAR(MAX)
    Set @erMsg = 'Test Error Severity:'+STR(@ErrorSeverity,3,0)+'State: '+STR(@ErrorState,3,0)
    RAISERROR(@erMSg,@ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState) WITH LOG
END

END
```

Comment: Can you show more code? Why do you think it *should* be a `Nullable<T>`? `SqlParameter` has a separate `IsNullable` property.

Comment: This makes little sense. SQL Server does not dictate the type of your parameter, that's only done by the client. It is perfectly legal (though confusing) to have an `INT` output parameter that is captured by a `long`-typed `SqlParameter`, for example. You should actually post the code you're using to execute the stored procedure. ADO.NET at its core does not support `Nullable` at all; instead all nulls are handled as `DBNull.Value`. Of course client libraries built on top of that (like Dapper) generally offer more convenience.

Comment: Incidentally, ``System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]&`` is the full internal name of what C# would call `ref int?`, which explains why `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` won't operate directly on it. `SqlParameter` does not use such types.

Comment: Though lacking the context of why you're doing this, the code to get `typeof(int)` out of such a type would be `Type paramType = typeof(myNullableParamInfo.ParameterType); Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(paramType.IsByRef ? paramType.GetElementType() : paramType)`. Again, note that this is only going to reflect over a .NET type which (hopefully) has been generated from the database declaration. If you want the *actual* parameter type of the stored procedure in the database, query `sys.parameters`.

Comment: Test SQL code added - I am attempting to cover the base condition where the OUTPUT parameter from SQL is potentially NULL - though through a generic method which can determine the returned type from the original method (return is via a webapi) - @Jeroen you are correct this is all within .Net

Comment: Again, on the ADO.NET level this is very simple -- the value will be `DBNull.Value`. If you're going through some kind of web API for the DB, you have nothing to do with SQL parameter values, because it's the web API you're talking to. Whether that calls a procedure at all or just makes things up on its own is transparent to you, and the stored procedure is actually not relevant to your question. Only the method interfaces to your API are.